# How can I blend these two meshes perfectly together without wrinkles?

Tags: vertices, edges, subdivision-surface, topology

I am modeling a Nissan Z GT500 car model and I have this problem on many parts of the car I don't know how to solve.

I want the "ducktail" part of the car to blend in the main body panels smoothly, but the best I can do is:

[image]

[image]

I get these nasty wrinkles no matter if I use edge crease or reinforce the edges with other edges. I know the it looks horrible with several tri-gons and edges too close to each other hence I ask for help. Auto smooth just makes everything 100% sharp but that's not how it looks on the real car...
This is done with Subdivision modifier with Levels Viewport set to 1.

I include a .blend file to examine the problem better: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ducLKRLXFEehvo_y1gVKfDBUpnFpFBar/view?usp=sharing

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe you should fix it with some support edge loops instead of *Edge Crease*? Something like that:

[image]